# How to preserve 'Date Modified' on a file

Tags: wix, wix3

I created an installer using wix. This installer has files that were last modified in 2009. But, when I run the installer, the files are installed and the 'Date Modified' in the explorer shows today's date (installer was run today). Is there a way to install a file and preserve its actual modified date?

Comment: What type of file is this?

Comment: Can we see the WiX source, at least a snipped of how you have configured the installation of files? What attributes do you set? Do you use Visual Studio? What settings for `candle.exe` and `light.exe` if you don't? And are you sure your source control system or some other factor doesn't affect the file dates? And finally and obviously: [distinguish between creation date and modified date](https://superuser.com/q/1180157/11906).

Comment: Sorry, this was a git behavior. The files were being retrieved from git and that caused the date issue

Comment: OK, if you have a fix, maybe add it yourself and set as accepted?